# WP-Rocket is not proccessing Remove unused CSS and Inline critical CSS

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, render-blocking

I'm using WP-Rocket to optimize my site speed with using Remove Unused Css functionality in Wp-Rocket. but somehow it's not generating critical CSS and not removing Unused CSS

- First it's showing wait for 80 seconds After that it's showing  `The Used CSS of your homepage has been processed. WP Rocket will continue to generate Used CSS for up to 100 URLs per 60 second(s).`
- I also checked with `WP cron Event` plug-in but it's showing `WP Rocket Remove Unused CSS pending jobs`
- I'm using cloudflare and Wordfence for security can it impact WP-Rocket?
  I also tried with Disable Cloudflare and learning mode in Wordfence.
  I tried with `clear and preload cache` and `clear used css` multiple times but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Cron should be running properly. This helps the action scheduler to properly process queued jobs for Remove Unused CSS.

User a server-side cron usually helps.

For Cloudflare and Wordfence, they might be blocking requests coming from the Remove Unused CSS crawler.

You will need to allow IPs related to the service. They can be found here - https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1628-which-ip-do-i-need-to-allow-for-wp-rocket